# error: target Objective-C runtime differs in PCH file vs. current file

Tags: objective-c, cmake, clang, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to compile Objective-C or `.m` file using command-line (generated by `CMake`) for `Catalyst`, but am stuck with two compile errors!

1. Whenever I enable `Catalyst` with one of below flags:

```
-target x86_64-apple-ios-macabi
-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi
-target x86_64-apple-ios13.5-macabi
-target x86_64-apple-ios13.7-macabi
```

2. Then force rebuild (click `Clean Build Folder`, then `Build`).

3. The build fails with error:

```
fatal error: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found
```

4. But once I switch to `13.6`, I mean, change the flag to:

```
-target x86_64-apple-ios13.6-macabi
```

5. Then force-rebuild, I get a new error:

```
error: target Objective-C runtime differs in PCH file vs. current file
```

> **Note** that I am not using any PCH file, and both errors seem completely confusing.

Also, I searched and found [post similar to second error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63360945/8740349), but the fix suggested (namely, switching to `13.6`) is the cause of the second error.
(Was supposed to fix it, yet is triggering it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After capturing Xcode's full command-line, I noticed that it had `-x objective-c` flag while my CMake had not!

After searching (about [how CMake support's Obj-C](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/3811/diffs)),
found actual mistake!

1. Basically, CMake needed me to do something like:

```
project(MyProject C CXX OBJC OBJCXX)
```

Instead of:

```
project(MyProject)
```

2. Also, should add Obj-C flags into `CMAKE_OBJC_FLAGS` instead of `CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS` variable.

3. Now CMake automaticaly adds missing `-x objective-c` flag, and I just need to add my custom flags.

---

Full Xcode command-line:

```
-x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios13.6-macabi -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -fmodule-name=MyProject -fapplication-extension -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -g -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping -index-store-path /MyBuildDir/Index/DataStore -iquote /MyBuildDir-cofig/MyProject-generated-files.hmap -I/MyBuildDir-cofig/MyProject-own-target-headers.hmap -I/MyBuildDir-cofig/MyProject-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /MyBuildDir-cofig/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /MyBuildDir-cofig/MyProject-project-headers.hmap -I/MyProductDir/include -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/iOSSupport/usr/include -I/MyBuildDir-cofig/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/MyBuildDir-cofig/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/MyBuildDir-cofig/DerivedSources -F/MyProductDir -iframework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /MyBuildDir-cofig/Objects-normal/x86_64/my-source.d --serialize-diagnostics /MyBuildDir-cofig/Objects-normal/x86_64/my-source.dia -c /Users/admin/my-project/my-source.m -o /MyBuildDir-cofig/Objects-normal/x86_64/my-source.o
```

**Note** that I replaced paths to shorten above, like:

```
MyBuildDir        => /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gczfeuobxydqjrfbdhwzpqjsseyr

MyBuildDir-config => /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gczfeuobxydqjrfbdhwzpqjsseyr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyProject.build/Debug-maccatalyst/MyProject.build/

MyProductDir      => /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gczfeuobxydqjrfbdhwzpqjsseyr/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst
```